# How solve missing package.json

Tags: macos, npm, terminal, npm-install

Hello my problem is when I try to remove any npm package o install my terminal show this warning

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/liantonypozo/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/liantonypozo/package.json'
```

some way to fix that without affecting the packages I have installed ?

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aibtN.png)

Comment: Is there a `/Users/liantonypozo/node_modules` folder? If not, you're just in the wrong directory.

Comment: I try in node_modules but the file is not in that directory

Comment: That's not what I asked. Does the folder `/Users/liantonypozo/node_modules` exist? If so, you probably *had* a `package.json` file in `/Users/liantonypozo` but somehow deleted it.

Comment: in `/Users/liantonypozo` exist package-lock.json  , I do not know why package.json reason was deleted , how to fix this error, since I have packages installed but I can not install or uninstall packages

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes I try your answer

Comment: Come **on**. Did it work? What happened when you tried? *Please* don't make folks drag needed info out of you.

Comment: I removed the node package and reinstalled it ,I think the file is deleted by a program that I have installed that cleans the mac

Answer (score 0):

How are you uninstalling? Do it via `npm uninstall packageName`. When you have problems, also try deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then doing `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, your list of packages are the *global* packages, because you ran `npm list` with the `-g` flag. You need to do the same with the uninstall command - `npm uninstall -g bower` - if you want to delete one of those globally installed packages.